# How to read word document on browser non IE

Tags: php, javascript, ms-word

I want to render word document (.doc, .docx) on broweser non I.E.
It's possible or not ?
If yes, how to be ?

Please share your experience.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Docs Viewer https://docs.google.com/viewer/

Example

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16123/upload/loremipsum.docx

Answer (score 1):

Only on client side: no. On server side with PHP: yes (it'll output as HTML)
And i bet that IE only support with a plugin too, with Office installed on the system.

Comment: On server side with PHP: yes (it'll output as HTML). Can you show to me examples and tutorial of that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680383/converting-ms-word-document-to-html-in-php