# PHP Convert Word file to HTML without losing styling and images

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, doc

Is there an API for converting word files to HTML without losing the format?

Can the google documents API be used for this?

I tried saaspose but the returning result is always a server error.

Solutions that did not work for me:

- [Converting MS Word document to html in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680383/converting-ms-word-document-to-html-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've spent a bit of time loking into this, and the best solution that I've found was to install [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) on the server, and using PHP to interface with it through system calls.

I would have loved to find a good native PHP solution for this, but unfortunately I couldn't.

**Edit**
Since originally answering this, I've come across a web service which presents an API for converting documents. I haven't tested it very thoroughly but it does seem to produce decent results at converting Word to HTML: [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.org/).

Comment: I guess we need a dedicated hosting for installing Openoffice/unoconv on the server.

Comment: You would most likely need dedicated hosting, yes.

Answer (score 0):

[PHPDocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) has a solution. According to site you may extract data directly from any database or spreadsheet and export them to other popular formats (PDF, DOC, HTML, ODT, ...) with the help of the conversion plugin. These reports may include editable graphs (only docx), images, tables, headers, footers, etcetera.

Am not sure how good it can convert word to html

Comment: You're right - PHPDocx should work for this. Unfortunately you'll need to buy a license in order to get the PHPDocx version that allows DOC/X to HTML.

Comment: Purchasing PHPDocx license is very expensive - $599.