# How to display file (for example ms office file) with its original formatting using php?

Tags: php, text, document

I have a big problem. I have made documents (`.docx` files) which I now want to put on my web site which I've made with php.

Is there any way to do that so that the documents don't lose their formatting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to convert word to html ?

Comment: yes! or somehow to add those formatted documents decently to my website. like blog articles or so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996527/php-convert-word-file-to-html-without-losing-styling-and-images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996527/php-convert-word-file-to-html-without-losing-styling-and-images)